# np.genfromtxt error in python 3

Tags: python, numpy, np

When I use

```
dataset = np.genfromtxt(open('data/train.csv','r'), delimiter=',', dtype='f8,str')[1:]
```

I obtain this error

```
TypeError: must be str or None, not bytes
```

Could you help me to find the solution?

Comment: Why not just `np.genfromtxt('data/train.csv', delimiter=',', dtype='f8,str')`?

Comment: In PY3 you need to open the file in 'rb' mode (or let it open it for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use open within `np.genfromtxt`:

```
dataset = np.genfromtxt('data/train.csv', delimiter=',', dtype='f8,str')[1:]
```

Comment: Thank you Neill!!